# UnitTesting Python scripts

Tags: python, aws-glue

I am Python newbie.

Is that possible to test Python script without wrapping code in functions / classes?

Let's say I want to cover with UTs this script https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-glue-samples/blob/master/examples/join_and_relationalize.py

Is that possible to write some UT https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html for it ?

The issue is: I can not run methods/functions in AWS Glue but only **script** is enter point for that Framework.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-python.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is that possible to test Python script without wrapping code in functions / classes?

You can just create unit tests which run the script itself (using `subprocess` for instance, checking that it has the correct retval / output).

> The issue is: I can not run methods/functions in AWS Glue but only script is enter point for that Framework.

That doesn't actually preclude writing functions (or even classes) unless AWS Glue specifically forbids doing so (which I'd find rather unlikely).

It's rather common for Python files to be both runnable scripts and importable libraries. You just need to "gate" the script entry point:

```py
def a_function():
    print("a function")

def main():
    a_function()

# magic!
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The last two lines are the magic bits: `__name__` is only equal to `"__main__"` if the file is being run as a script.

This means if you run the above file it'll immediately print "a function", but if you `import` it, it won't do anything until you call `a_function()` (or `main()`).

Comment: yes, it works! Thank you very much @Masklinn for this magic :) But how to test code that is inside magic bits? Is that supposed to be uncovered or there are some approaches to test it 100% ?

Comment: There's no way to run them aside from runnig the script itself. Usually if you want to maximise coverage you'd ignore those and only call a function, which you can then test and cover (the only actually magic part is `__name__` so technically you can have as much code as you want in there).